# Understanding default Rest Api

Tags: rest

Which one of the options below do you purpose to use in web API and why ?
all endpoints are GET methods

Option 1

```
persons
persons/active
persons/deactive
persons/deleted
```

Option 2

```
persons/all
persons/active
persons/deactive
persons/deleted
```

Option 3

```
persons/all
persons
persons/deactive
persons/deleted
```

Comment: This is an opinionated question, but for me, option 1 would make most sense. Although, I'm curious as to what `/persons` would return on option 3 if you already have `/persons/all`

Comment: @James in option 3 /persons would return only active users

Comment: @BurimHajrizaj ah, course, makes sense - misleading IMO though as "active" users would most likely be a filter on the collection